# suspicious pointer conversion on taking long int

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    long int i,t,n,q[500],d[500],s[500],res[500]={0},j,h;
    scanf("%ld",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%ld %ld",&n,&h);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            scanf("%ld %ld",&d[i],&s[i]);
        for(i=0;i<h;i++)
            scanf("%ld",&q[i]);
        for(i=0;i<h;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                res[j]=d[j]+q[i]*s[j];
            }
        j=cal(res,n,q[i],s);
        printf("%ld\n",j);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

long int cal(int res[],int n,int q,int s[])
{
    long int i,max=0,p,pos=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if (max==res[i])
        {
            pos=add(res,s,pos,i,q);
            max=res[pos];
        }
        if (res[i]>max)
        {
                max=res[i];
                pos=i;
        }
    }
    return pos;
}
```

Whenever I am taking variable as `int`, it's working fine, but if I am declaring a variable as `long int`, I am getting warning message as "suspicious pointer conversion" in function call — in the line:

```
(j=cal(res,n,q[i],s));
```

Can you please explain the reason?

Comment: can you post the prototype of cal() function

Comment: Well, it'd be helpful if we knew what `cal` looked like. Sorry, but solar flares are interfering with our crystal balls.

Comment: @NikBougalis Good one :)

Answer (score 4):

Given:

1. `long int i,t,n,q[500],d[500],s[500],res[500]={0},j,h;`
2. `j=cal(res,n,q[i],s);` and
3. `long int cal(int res[],int n,int q,int s[])`

you are trying to pass the array `long res[500]` to a function that expects an array of `int`.  Even if `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long)` on your machine, the types are different — and the sizes are definitely different on my machine.

If you're on Windows (32-bit or 64-bit) or on 32-bit Unix, you'll get away with it, but if you migrate to an LP64 64-bit environment, all hell will break loose.

That's why it is a 'suspicious pointer conversion'.  It isn't kosher; it isn't reliable; it happens to work on your environment (but it is extremely dubious for portability reasons).

---

> But why is it giving a warning as "suspicious pointer conversion" (instead of the expected message as "L-Value required")?

I'm not sure why you'd expect an `l-value required` error.  Remember that when you call a function, arrays decay into pointers, so your function declaration could also be written `long cal(int *res, int n, int q, int *s)`, and you're passing `long res[500]` which is automatically changed to `long *` (as if you'd written `&res[0]`), so you're passing a `long *` where an `int *` is expected, and you'll probably get away with it (hence the 'suspicious' rather than anything more serious).

Consider the code:

```
long res[500];
long cal(int res[]);

int main(void)
{
    return cal(res);
}
```

GCC 4.7.1 on a 64-bit machine (and 64-bit compilation) says:

```
x.c: In function ‘main’:
x.c:6:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘cal’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
x.c:2:6: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘long int *’
```

*(I don't often see people writing `long int` instead of just `long`, so I've gone with the usual practice of dropping the `int` from `long int`.  You're correct that `long int` is valid and legal and means the same thing as `long`; most people don't write the extra word, that's all.)*

Comment: But why it's giving warning as "suspicious pointer conversion" (as expected message as "L-Value required ) ???

Answer (score 0):

ISO C 9899 says in 6.3.1.1 under arithmetic operand

```
The rank of long long int shall be greater than the rank of long int, which
shall be greater than the rank of int, which shall be greater than the rank of short
int, which shall be greater than the rank of signed char
```

KnR ANSI C version says in 2.2 data types and sizes

```
short is often 16 bits long, and int either 16 or 32 bits. Each compiler is free to     choose appropriate sizes for its own
hardware, subject only to the the restriction that shorts and ints are at least 16     bits, longs are
at least 32 bits, and short is no longer than int, which is no longer than long.
```

conclusion : dont cast long to int. you will lose data causing bugs.convert your parameters to type long. it can take int as well as long int.